# As SSDs get faster and Level 2 caches get bigger, could RAM become redundant?

Tags: memory, ssd

If Solid State Drives become sufficiently fast that they aren't that much slower than RAM, and Level-2 caches get larger; is it possible to build a PC that doesn't have any RAM at all? What would the advantages/disadvantages of this be? Are there any examples of computers/operating systems that do this already?

This might be a naive question to the hardcore tech guys but I'd love to hear some thoughts/ideas/answers.

Comment: IMOHO it would be best to interact with a buffered copy of the OS rather than the OS in its persistent state. But then again Knoppix is persistent on a USB drive, so it's not that far off...

Comment: In the discount server world, OpenVZ allows you to take an SSD and use it as RAM for its virtual machines. It's not as fast but it's much cheaper. There's also a lifespan issue, as I believe RAM gets written to a lot more than a regular drive does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i would say that RAM is still very important to modern computers and, without a major jump in technology, it will remain important for the foreseeable future. For active applications the speed of RAM (3.2 - 12.8 GB/s) far out-weighs the relative stellar performance of SATA3 with a compatible SSD (280 - 590 MB/s)

Tom's Hardware reviews (of course anything on the internet requires some salt)

[RAM (DDR2 and DDR3)](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/ram-speed-tests,1807-3.html)

[SSD + SATA2 & SATA3](http://www.tomshardware.com/news/Seagate-AMD-SATA3-Standard,7223.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! By the way, the new HSDL drives are pushing above 800MB/s in the right conditions. Granted, they're still a long way off comparing to RAM in terms of speed.

Comment: Plus the memory controller is built on the CPU these days giving even better speeds. Like Xantec said it'll be a long time before RAM is totally done away with. We are just now scratching the surface of SSDs and even if they were a lot faster than they are now I'm thinking it would require some hefty hardware rethinking by Intel/AMD and chipset manufacturers.

Answer (score 3):

External RAM will still be necessary for a long time, since it is one of the few sane ways to share state between cores on different CPUs.